# avaialbility monitorning using new relic

Tags: newrelic

Hi I would like to add a ping to my site using new relic's availability monitoring.I can add the monitorning, but all the times I am getting failures, even if the site is running. How to test the connectivity first to ensure new relic is talking to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that New Relic's Availability Monitoring service can reach the URL you set for pinging.  Currently the service sends requests from following addresses:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/networks#availability

```
50.18.57.7
50.31.164.139
50.112.95.211
54.247.188.179
54.248.250.232
54.251.34.67
177.71.245.207
184.73.237.85
204.93.223.151
```

Also, be sure to verify that the settings "Treat redirects as a valid result", "Validate SSL certificate" and "Substring required in response for a valid result" are set appropriately for your URL and configuration.

If the problems your are having with Availability Monitoring are more intermittent, the following document has some great troubleshooting information:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/troubleshooting-for-availability-monitoring

If you still have trouble, file a support ticket with support.newrelic.com